# Use Custom Method to Display date in form mm/dd/yyyy from return output

Tags: java

I need to create a method that will display the date in format mm/dd/yyyy when the method is accessed through a printf statement. This is an assignment and I cannot use java.util.Date Class.

The date value must be returned through the method so it can be printed with

```
System.out.printf("Date 1 is %s%n%n", date1.displayDate())
```

I have tried converting the instance variables for month, day, and year to Strings and then putting the String values into an array but when I do that all I'm getting is the first value of each of the indexes printed into the returned value.

I need to have the whole date in format mm/dd/yyyy returned but I'm not sure if I can iterate the entire array and then save that value into a variable to return.

Here is my driver class...

```
public class DriverClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //  DATE CLASS FUNCTIONALITY TEST
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        DateClass date1 = new DateClass(07,21,1987);
        DateClass date2 = new DateClass(01, 22, 1999);
        DateClass date3 = new DateClass(04,17,1945);

        System.out.printf("Date 1 is %s%n%n", date1.displayDate());
        System.out.printf("Date 2 is %s%n%n", date2.displayDate());
        System.out.printf("Date 3 is %s%n%n", date3.displayDate());
    }
}
```

Here is my code...

```
public class DateClass {

    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    public DateClass(int monthIn, int dayIn, int yearIn){
        month=monthIn;
        day=dayIn;
        year=yearIn;
    }


    //get and set methods
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month){
        this.month=month;
    }

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day=day;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year=year;
    }



    public String[] displayDate(){

        String sMonth = Integer.toString(month);
        String sDay = Integer.toString(day);
        String sYear = Integer.toString(year);

            String dayAR[] = new String[5];
            dayAR[0] = sMonth;
            dayAR[1] = "/";
            dayAR[2] = sDay;
            dayAR[3] = "/";
            dayAR[4] = sYear;

            return dayAR;

    }

}
```

Comment: By the way, `Date` class is terrible and was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Comment: Alright, thank you for letting me know. I did not know that.

Comment: For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone or offset-from-UTC, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class. That class offers all the methods you are re-creating here. I understand you are doing a homework exercise here for learning, but in real-work you would use `LocalDate` rather than re-invent the class. The legacy classes `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` were replaced by `java.time.Instant` and `java.time.LocalDate`, respectively.

Comment: Excellent, good to know. thank you vary much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `displayDate()` method should return a `String` instead of a `String[]`.

```
return sMonth + "/" + sDay + "/" + sYear;
```

This won't quite work though, you would also need to do some bounds checking so that the values can be padded with zeros. For instance you want `01/01/0001` not `1/1/1`.

I would avoid implementing a bunch of bounds checking though, just use an existing tried-and-true method for formatting strings. I suggest using [`String.format(format, ...args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to do the heavy lifting unless explicitly disallowed.

```
return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
```

This solution still isn't perfect, it doesn't account for values that are not valid, but that should be done when the values are being set, not when the string is being generated.

Comment: That seems to have worked, I just removed the array and fixed the return statement. But I did notice that when the "month" variable is value 08 or 09 it says "integer number too large" but if it's 9 or 8 it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format` to help get the formatting right. For example:

```
String.format("%d/%d/%d", 1, 20, 1995); // Produces "1/20/1995"
```

The documentation for Java String format syntax (like the `%d` and `%s`) is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

You'll probably want to prefix days and months with a zero if they are only a single digit.

(Just wanted to give a hint since this is an assignment but let me know if you get stuck)

Comment: Thanks for the hint that helped aswell. :)